# driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); returning error when using current version of Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a regression pack for an online app using ChromeDriver on Version 42.0.2311.90 m of Google Chrome, and am having issues when trying to return focus from an iFrame back to the main screen, i.e. upon hitting the line of code 
**driver.switchTo().defaultContent();**

This worked perfectly on earlier versions of Chrome, and still works fine on a colleagues pc which has Version 39.x.etc

Has anyone else encountered anything similar ?  If so, any help / advice / workaround would be greatly appreciated.

The code for the particular Java method is:

```
@When("I click the $buttonText button in AllFinanz")
public void clickButtonInAllFinanz(String buttonText) throws InterruptedException {
     System.out.println("[TEST] Clicking " + buttonText);
     try {
          // access inside iframe
          WebElement elementFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@onload, 'riskAssessmentIframe')]"));
  driver.switchTo().frame(elementFrame);

           // click the button
           WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='" + buttonText + "']"));
           button.click();

           // return focus to main window
           driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

   Thread.sleep(sleepTime*5);
           System.out.println("[SUCCESS] Clicked button " + buttonText);

     } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
          System.out.println("[FAILURE] Unable to click button " + buttonText);
     } catch (org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException e) {
          System.out.println("[FAILURE] " + buttonText + " not visible");
     }
}
```

As stated all works fine up until the driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); line of code, where the following error is thrown back:

> **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: missing 'id'**
>   (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.90) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86) (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information) System info:
>   os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_45' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Again any help would be appreciated - I've ran out of ideas re workarounds and cant find any answers when googling.

Thanks,
Barry.

Comment: Just for the sake of determining the cause of the problem, add `Thread.sleep(5000)` before switching to the default content. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Hi Alecxe,
That was my first attempt at workaround - unfortunately didnt work.
Have also tried focusing on the iFrame again before switching back to default content, incase it had lost focus...also tried ignoring the default switch altogether in case it had automatically switched back on button click...but both these didnt work either.  It def appears to be still focussed on the 'riskAssessmentIframe' and fails when trying to switch back to default content.
Just really strange that it works fine on older version of Chrome on colleague's pc

Comment: Alright, thanks. How about upgrading chromedriver to the latest version and selenium to 2.46?

Answer (score 0):

As per exception your Chrome Ver is 42 and ChromeDriver is 2.10. As per below change notes, ChromeDriver 2.10 supports up to 36.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/notes.txt

Good to use latest chromedriver, lets see is it working fine or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
await driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());    
el = driver.switchTo().alert();
await el.accept();
```

Check out the docs for all languages https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/